# jquery hover effect image gallery buggy at firefox

Tags: jquery

i would like to look or find solution for firefox browser that keep my **hover effect image gallery** buggy except in chrome browser.

please feel free to look at my codes where you can see the full issues in firefox browser. currently here's my short code for image fadeIn and fadeOut..

```
theBigImage.fadeOut(250, function(){
  theBigImage.attr('src', imageHref).fadeIn(250);
});
```

Then check this
[jsfiddle hover effect image gallery](http://jsfiddle.net/imarkdesigns/MWRTD/12/) for the full source code while viewing it in firefox and chrome.

Comment: i believe the cache is my issue here in firefox...

Comment: what's the "buggy" part?

Comment: when you try to hover at each text, there was a delay at firefox. delay that once you hover to another text, the last image will not hide until the 2nd image will show or become visible. which is not happening in chrome browser.